# How can I customize Bootstrap with Sass if I use it via CDN?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

The [Bootstrap 5.3 doc on Sass customization](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/) explains how to override Bootstrap settings using the Sass `custom.scss` script. I understand that, when Bootstrap was downloaded either manually or via the package manager, the `custom.scss` script needs to refer to these downloaded files, with something like `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`.

However, suppose I did not download Bootstrap, but instead I want to [import Bootstrap via CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start), like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can I still use the same approach? If so, what path should I specify in the `@import` command?

Comment: Why are you unsure about the import path URL? Have you tried it?

Comment: @isherwood how the path could possibly work if I didn't download anything to "node_modules" dir? I don't even have node.js or npm installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import external files to your custom.scss like this:

```scss
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

But I would recommend downloading Bootstrap via package manager or manually instead.